Why do I have the lxd process running with docker?
I'm new to the docker world, but I'm familiar with the differences between Docker and LXC/LXD. Although Docker previously used LXC for creating and managing containers, it has since evolved to use its own containerization technology. I think docker uses containerd now, right?
My main question is: Why on some servers can I see containerd under the lxc user? Am I using lxc without knowing it?
sudo ps aux | grep lxc
lxc         797  0.3  4.6 2210836 93536 ?       Ssl  23:45   0:02 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Thanks for helping guys.

What operating system are you running?

@NickODell I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, the network is IPv6 only.
